# Property 'Authorization' does not exist on type 'HeadersDefaults'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am doing an Authorization with react and typescript, but i am facing the problem where at the line of code `axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')} ';`give me and error like this

> Property 'Authorization' does not exist on type
> 'HeadersDefaults'.ts(2339)

Below is my index.tsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
axios..Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')} `;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Please how i can solve this error. By the way i attach also my `package.json`

```
   {
  "name": "react-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']`: you’re missing the `common` key in the middle. Refer to their docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam i already try to lower case but still same

Answer (score 1):

**Try**:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code sets authorization headers for all requests:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`;
```

This code sets authorization headers for all post requests:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`;
```